# printing to screen counter value of an array in system.out.print.ln

Tags: java, arrays, loops, counter

I am trying to enter Strings into an array Input by user - using Scanner.
I am prompting user for total amount of students and saving this in a variable to determine array length.
Each loop I would like to ask the question "what is the name of student" (and their position in counter) ie student #1 student# 2 etc
The below code seems to be working as is.

```
System.out.println("what is first name of student")
```

when I add to the end of this + counter+ I get an error message "illegal start of expression"

Please help, and find entire code below. Thanks

```
public class Student
{
    public static void main(String[]args)//Main method
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int studentNumber;// declare a variable to store # students

        System.out.println( "Please enter the number of students.");

        noStudent=input.nextInt();//take in user input for number of racers

        while (noStudent<2 || noStudent>20)// validate users 
        {
            //while users input is invalid, alert user and prompt user for a valid number
            System.out.println("Invalid input please re-enter a number between 2 and 20.");
            noStudent=input.nextInt();
        }

        String[] nameArray = new String[noStudent];

        for(int counter = 0; counter<nameArray.length; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("please enter first name of student "  + i+);  
            nameArray[counter] = input.next();
        }
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do (if it's java):

```
for(int counter = 0; counter<nameArray.length; counter++)
{
System.out.println("please enter first name of student "  + (counter+1));  
nameArray[counter] = input.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("please enter first name of student "  + i+);
```

Should be

```
System.out.println("please enter first name of student "  + counter);
```

Also, I think you may want to declare the variable `noStudent` instead of `studentNumber`. You're using `noStudent` a bunch of times, but I don't see it declared. And I see `studentNumber` declared, but I don't see it ever used.

```
int noStudent;
System.out.println( "Please enter the number of students.");
noStudent=input.nextInt();
```